# Can I force my Pi (4B) to boot attached mechanical drives **after** one another, instead of simultaneously?

Tags: power, hub

I'm still trying to workaround to attach multiple 3.5 HDDs on my Raspberry Pi 4B without a [centralised hub](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powered+USB+hub&t=ffnt&ia=web). Everytime my Raspi Boots, or boots up the drives, it does so with booting all of them at once.

This causes a power problem, because the spinning up of the mechanical drives draws too much power and the Pi is stuck in an infinite boot loop.

Any ideas, boys?

Comment: You could create a background script that mounted the first drive waited then mounted the second, but this is a kludge.

Comment: There are ways to control power to usb ports.  look into uhubctl.  In addition to controlling the hub built into the pi, some external hubs support this too.

Comment: I'm gonna agree and disagree with @SteveRobillard in that I think using a script here is not a kludge -- ideally there would (and might) be a systemd feature to tweak this, but it would probably take less time to write the script than to dig around for that.  You then want them in `/etc/fstab` with `noauto`.  I'll post an example later...

Comment: The problem, though, may well be that it's **nothing to do with mounting** and just the power coming on and something that can't be controlled by the pi (although what @Abel mentions could turn them off again quickly).  You could test this by using `noauto` in `fstab` without a script to mount them (so they end up not being mounted).

Comment: If mounting alone solves it (I'm pretty sure its hardware dependent and may vary with different drives), you can modify the auto-mounting algorithm to take a lock and release it after some amount of spin-up time or use locks to limit how many disks can be mounted at once (safer).

Comment: @goldilocks I consider it a kludge because while it may work, it does not do so by solving the root cause of the problem (which is likely a power issue).

Comment: @Abel: In general, `uhubctl` is not well-supported in hardware. Refer to its GitHub page for details.

Comment: What exactly is ***multiple***? 2, or 200? If it's a power issue, this is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the drives on first, then they will have power going with them already running. That is what I do with my single spinner and the SSD attached to it. Good luck with it the USB is so flaky on these things. If I am stupid enough to leave the keyboard attached I get a no boot in this configuration with my Pi 4. If trying to do this drawing the power from the Pi it will never work, you can only get 1.2A power drawn from the ports combined for all 4 USB ports. If you do not know 1.2A x 5V = 6 Watts of total power it can supply.

Comment: You might want to mention the possibility of using a powered hub instead of powering all from the RPi's USB ports.

Comment: He had mentioned in his posting before whoever edited it, he wanted to avoid a powered hub now it says centralized for some reason, whoever thought this was a better wording for it is beyond me.

Comment: Ah - yeah - I see that now. So your answer then is to stagger the start times and thereby avoid the *inrush* current of multiple disks starting at once?

Comment: Have them on at the start of the machine, then the surge to spin up current draw is gone, yes. Turning them on afterwards does no good the spin up still happens then. Looking at old 500gb drive here it is 5v @ .345A simply running for well over quarter of the 1.2A it can do who knows how much during the spin up.